# Using RegExp in IIS rewrite statements

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I have a set of pages I need to rewrite to a handler using IIS's web.config file. The final structure should look like this:

mydomain.com/es/mexico

This needs to get mapped to:

international.php?lang=es&country=mexico

The language code, however, won't always be there - so if someone types in "mydomain.com/mexico" it should be redirected to:

international.php?country=mexico

I tried to set this up in my web.config, but whenever I try to add a second querystring I hit a web.config server error. Can anyone help?

Comment: a copy of the error could be useful.

Comment: The current code I am using to get at least the country part to work is             <rule name="Rewrite international pages">
             <match url="^international/([a-z _]+)" />
             <action type="Rewrite" url="international.php?country={R:1}" />
            </rule>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
^(?:/([A-Za-z0-9]{2})?)?(?:/(.{3,}))
```

*language* (2 letters) will be matched to **{R:1}**

*country* (3+ letters) will be matched to **{R:2}**